# Laravel 5 console info lines

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, console, laravel-artisan

When I run "`php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`" everything works as expected - I get info lines with all actions

```
(Rolled back: migration, Migrated: migration, Seeded: seeder)
```

I am calling the same command in console "`Artisan::call('migrate:refresh', ['--seed' => true]);`". It works fine but it is not showing the info lines

```
(rolled back, migrated, seeded).
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: Take a look at this interface https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Console/Kernel.php#L23 it returns int, so you are not missing anything. Would it make sense to return string inside your php script? Would you parse it in order to know if it was success or fail?

Comment: I just want to display the logs: "Rolled back: migration 1, Rolled back: migration 2". If I call the command from another command it runs it but it does not display the logs.